# Consumir API YouTube v3 com React Native para listar vídeos em uma FlatList

Tags: api, react-native, axios, youtube-api

preciso muito da ajuda de vocês, sou iniciante em **React Native** e quero fazer uma Flatlist com os **videos** de uma canal do **YouTube**, porém eu não sei como fazer a integração do **AXIOS** ou **fecht** com a **FletList** e assim listar.

Isso eu já consegui fazer com **JavaScript** puro na WEB em 2 horas, mas no React estou a 3 dias e nada.

Se alguém que já saiba como fazer poder fazer um exemplo simples de uma página só pra que eu possa entender, como foi feito.

Eu estou usando essa API do **YouTube v3** pra fazer o **GET** pela minha aplicação.

```
const API = axios.create({
   baseURL:`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${api_key}&channelId=${channel_id}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=${max_results}`
})
```